# How does Select query work with Distinct clause

Tags: sql, select

Can anyone explain in detail why the following query does not work?

```
select dept_id, distinct job_id from employees
```

Also please suggest some resource which helps to understand the inner workings of SQL queries?

Comment: It's `SELECT DISTINCT`, and it works on the whole selected rows, not just one column.

Comment: Put the `distinct` keyword after the `select` : `select distinct dept_id, job_id from employees`

Comment: @jarlh That's what I am asking that why it does not work on one column? What if I want unique jobs for all departments?

Comment: Then you can use GROUP BY. Add sample table data and the expected result to your question, to describe what you want.

Comment: as Jarth suggested.. you should be more clear about your expectations and results ..

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: "What if I want unique jobs for all departments" - one thing you should learn is that SQL doesn't have any inherent "left to right" evaluation of the `SELECT` clause (nor `WHERE` predicates). Each expression in the `SELECT` list is evaluated independently and not in the context of those expressions that appear to the left of them.

Comment: *"...why it does not work on one column?"* - Perhaps this is something that simply needs you to sit and think about it for a while. The way `DISTINCT` works is quite logical - how can you have a single distinct column without its output affecting other columns? Either the whole result set is `DISTINCT` or it isn't.

Comment: @pratikgarg: I am using Oracle DB. I know we can use group by. In an interview I was asked why distinct cannot be written like this? And the answer lies somewhere in the internal implementation of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT is used to get set of unique rows. By other words, DISTINCT option cuts repeatable rows from a result. Most of times (most of db's actualy) you can't use distinct on not all but just some columns due to uncertainty of data.

Just for example, if your employees table looks like

```
Emp_id Dept_id Job_id
1      24      117
2      24      117
3      24      118
4      25      117
```

and you want to get list of unique jobs for every department, first you should try

```
SELECT Dept_id, Job_id
  FROM Employees
```

so result will be like:

```
24 117
24 117
24 118
25 117
```

Notice that now row "24 117" is doubled due to two employees with same job in one department. So, DISTINCT will cut duplicated rows in your result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Dept_id, Job_id
  FROM Employees
```

gives:

```
24 117
24 118
25 117
```

But if you want DB to give you result of

```
SELECT Dept_id, DISTINCT Job_id
```

your DB won't be able to guess what exactly Dept_id you want to recieve in pair with 117 Job_id (choice is like "24 or 24 or 25?"). So if you want to get only distinct job_id's and some dept_id's along with them you should specify which exactly dept_id you want to see in you result if there will be many of them. For example you may get a minimum dept_id or something like that:

```
SELECT MIN(Dept_id) AS Dept_id, Job_id
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Job_id
```

with a result like:

```
24 117
24 118
```

It's all about certainty and uncertainty. In a sql query you should always specify what exactly you want.

Comment: Thanks @Nlink.. "DB won't be able to guess what exactly Dept_id you want to recieve in pair with 117 Job_id " that's the crucial line!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, I think you want to get unique job ids for all the departments.

Just try this query :

```
SELECT dept_id, job_id FROM employees Group By dept_id, job_id
```

Table

Dept_id | Job_id

```
1      1
1      2
1      3
1      3
2      2
2      3  
2      4  
2      4  
3      1  
3      4  
4      1
```

Run the query, you will get the below results.

Dept_id | Job_id

```
1      1
1      2
1      3
2      2
2      3  
2      4  
3      1  
3      4  
4      1
```

Comment: GROUP BY without aggregate functions - why? (Same as `SELECT DISTINCT dept_id, job_id...`)

Comment: even if you use distinct, you will get the same records. Its also correct.

Comment: If you want to do `SELECT DISTINCT` in funny ways, you can also do `SELECT dept_id, job_id FROM employees UNION SELECT dept_id, job_id FROM employees`.

Comment: "What if I want unique jobs for all departments"?
for this you can use either 

SELECT DISTINCT dept_id, job_id FROM employees
OR
SELECT dept_id, job_id FROM employees Group By dept_id, job_id

Comment: @jarlh
It is man, but if you go with union its going to slow down the process for sure.

Comment: It was more of a "having fun with SQL" comment!